# Nested 'for' Loop to Create Table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been working through a course called "The Odin Project", and I have hit a wall on a project were we have to create an Etch-A-Sketch like sketchpad.

The gist of the project is... Whenever you mouse over a cell in the table, a class is added to that cell that changes the color. I have created some code using jQuery/javascript to create a square grid by appending table rows and cells using two 'for' loops (see script below).

My issue is whenever I run the 'for' loops with the append code to create the grid I do not get a square grid. For example, I would think setting up both of the 'for' loops to a limit of 4 should give me a grid with 4 rows with 4 cells a piece. What I am actually getting is the first row has 16 cells, second row has 12 cells, etc... Where am I going wrong here?

Link to jsfiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/rellbows/qka0ago7/1/

```
for (var w = 0; w < 4; w++) {
  $('tbody').append('<tr></tr>');
  for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    $('tr').append('<td class="square"></td>');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to append the square `td` elements to the last `tr` element you just created. You were appending the `td` elements to *all* the `tr` elements.

You can either use the [`:last` selector](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/), or the [`.last()` method](https://api.jquery.com/last/) for this.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/6vjp5932/)

```
$('tr:last').append('<td class="square"></td>');
```

You could also just create a `tr` element, append the `td` elements to it, and *then* append that `tr` element to the table:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/emd5hp8f/)

```
for (var w = 0; w < 4; w++) {
    var $tr = $('<tr></tr>');
    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        $tr.append('<td class="square"></td>');
    }
    $('tbody').append($tr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the each table cell to every `tr` tag that has come before.

Instead, you should identify each row and append the current row's cells to that row.

```
for (var w = 0; w < 4; w++) {
    $('tbody').append('<tr id="row' + w + '"></tr>');
    for(var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        $('#row' + w).append('<td class="square"></td>');
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qka0ago7/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qka0ago7/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    for (var w = 0; w < 4; w++) {
            $('tbody').append('<tr>');
                for(var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    $('tbody').append('<td class="square"></td>');
                }
            $('tbody').append('</tr>');
        }

})
```

Two changes... first you must always append onto the same element 'tbody'.  Using $(tr) was appending onto ALL of the `<tr>` tags.
Second the start and end td tags need to be on each side of the inner loop.